# Get Country borders through openstreetmap API

Tags: python, openstreetmap

i want to draw a map of Europe. For that i need the country outlines as polygons. For that i want to use the openstreetmap API.

I played around a bit with `overpy` but my result for a single country took 10 minutes to execute and doesn't look right (seems like the ways do not fit together).

My code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()

result=api.query("area['name:en'='Denmark']->.country;rel['name:en'='Denmark']['type'='boundary']['admin_level'='2'];(way(r)['maritime' != 'yes'](40,-10,70,80);way(area.country)['natural'='coastline'](40,-10,70,80););out geom;")

x=[]
y=[]
i=0
for way in result.ways:
    print(f"way {i} of {len(result.ways)}")
    i=i+1
    for node in way.get_nodes(True):
        x.append(float(node.lon))
        y.append(float(node.lat))
plt.plot(x, y,label=str(way.id))
plt.show()
```

Am i on the right track or is there a way better solution? Thanks!

[image: matplotliboutput]

[image: example map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is all right, just use points and not lines. I also have no solution for the long runtime. [image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()

result=api.query("area['name:en'='Denmark']->.country;rel['name:en'='Denmark']['type'='boundary']['admin_level'='2'];(way(r)['maritime' != 'yes'](40,-10,70,80);way(area.country)['natural'='coastline'](40,-10,70,80););out geom;")

x=[]
y=[]
i=0
for way in result.ways:
    print(f"way {i} of {len(result.ways)}")
    if 'natural' in way.tags and way.tags['natural']=='coastline' and len(way.get_nodes(True))>0: #just a test
        i=i+1
        for node in way.get_nodes(True):
            print (f'lon: {float(node.lon):3.4f}; lat: {float(node.lat):3.4f}')
            x.append(float(node.lon))
            y.append(float(node.lat))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o',label=str(way.id))
plt.show()
```

---

EDIT due to polygons:

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import overpy


def getData():
    api = overpy.Overpass()
    result = api.query("area['name:en'='Denmark']->.country;rel['name:en'='Denmark']['type'='boundary']['admin_level'='2'];(way(r)['maritime' != 'yes'](40,-10,70,80);way(area.country)['natural'='coastline'](40,-10,70,80););out geom;")

    x = []
    y = []
    i = 0
    for way in result.ways:
        print(f"way {i} of {len(result.ways)}")
        # just a test
        if 'natural' in way.tags and way.tags['natural'] == 'coastline' and len(way.get_nodes(True)) > 0:
            i = i+1
            x1 = []
            y1 = []
            for node in way.get_nodes(True):
                print(
                    f'lon: {float(node.lon):3.4f}; lat: {float(node.lat):3.4f}')
                x1.append(float(node.lon))
                y1.append(float(node.lat))
            x.append(x1)
            y.append(y1)

    xy = [x, y]
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(xy, f)


def readDate():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)


getData()
data = readDate()


last = None
first = None
d = []
k = [[], []]
m = []
while(len(data[0]) > 0):
    if last == None and first == None:   # Make sure that there are no "ways" at the beginning or end that match the line.
        last = [data[0][0][-1], data[1][0][-1]] # Get first and last point of a new line
        first = [data[0][0][0], data[1][0][0]]
        k[0] = k[0] + data[0][0] # Start the new line
        k[1] = k[1] + data[1][0]
        data[0].pop(0) # Drop the way
        data[1].pop(0) 
    for j in range(0, len(data[0])): # Check all lines

        if first == [data[0][j][-1], data[1][j][-1]]: # If the first ...
            print(f'First {first[0]}; {first[1]}')
            k = [data[0][j] + k[0], data[1][j] + k[1]]
            first = [data[0][j][0], data[1][j][0]]
            data[0].pop(j)
            data[1].pop(j)
            break

        if last == [data[0][j][0], data[1][j][0]]: # or the last point continue the current line
            print(f'Last  {last[0]}; {last[1]}')
            k = [k[0] + data[0][j], k[1] + data[1][j]] # Add the segment to the new line
            last = [data[0][j][-1], data[1][j][-1]] # Set the point new last point
            data[0].pop(j) # Drop the way
            data[1].pop(j)
            break

        if j == len(data[0])-1: # When the for-loop reaches the end, there is no "way" that continue the line
            m.append(k)
            k = [[], []]
            first = None
            last = None

    if len(data[0]) == 1: # If the last remaining line is a small island, just add it.
        k = [data[0][0], data[1][0]]
        m.append(k)
        data[0].pop(0)
        data[1].pop(0)


for i in range(0, len(m)):
    plt.plot(m[i][0], m[i][1], label=f'Denmark')

plt.show()
```

This algorithm arranges the "ways" from the API in a way that creates polygons where possible.

[image]

Comment: i need polygons, so this is unfortunately not a valid solution.

Comment: @MarvinNoll, added a possible solution for the polygon problem. May not be perfect but a start.